# Bug list for Mathematica releases

Tags: installation

Is there a list of confirmed bugs in various Mathematica releases and in which release these bugs were corrected?
E.g. 10 - 10.3 were quite buggy (at least for my purpose), 10.4.1 corrected quite some bugs. From the forum it seems that 11.0 is quite bad, and some were solved in 11.1.
I wanted to update Mathematica at university but the question arises, to which version, or which of the latest versions is least buggy...

Comment: I do not know of any such list; however, I think a more relevant question would be about bugs for which there are no known workarounds. Which version is best would depend on what you typically do and to what extent the bugs without workarounds would impact on what you are likely to do and what benefit you gain from enhancements in versions, i.e., it is highly subjective.